# get node position after physics calculation scenekit

Tags: ios, swift3, scenekit

[image]

Working on a scenekit application, I have 2 boxes that can fire shots to each other for points. This is the calculation of the position where shots need to be made for the first box :

```
shot1 = SCNNode()
shot1.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
shot1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
shot1.position = SCNVector3Make
(boxNode1.position.x, 
 boxNode1.position.y + 1, 
 boxNode1.position.z - 1)
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(shot1)
```

And for the second box :

```
shot2 = SCNNode()
shot2.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
shot2.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
shot2.position = SCNVector3Make
(boxNode2.position.x, 
 boxNode2.position.y + 1, 
 boxNode2.position.z + 1)
scnScene.rootNode.addChileNode(shot2)
```

Every shot is made just in good position and is thrown to the other box with applying force on its physicsBody as impulse.

For touch implementation I used touchesBegan to search for touches, then if the touch have the hitResult, I fire shots as I described above.

The problem happens where :
If the shot for example shot1 hit boxNode2, the boxNode2 is moved backward as I expect it and this time if I fire a shot with boxNode2, the starting position of shot2 IS NOT in NEW location of boxNode2 as I expect it, and is starting to fire right where it was at the beginning!

So how can I fire shots from new position of the boxNodes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `presentation`:

```
let realPosition = yourNode.presentation.worldPosition
```

Comment: Thanks man, it really works! now I need to find a way to analyze changing the impulse angle if the shot caused the box rotation on y axis.

Comment: Thanks, dude. Helped me a lot this.